# Confusion with USB A-B type color code

Tags: usb

I have a USB A-B type cable, where there are 4 color wires:

BLACK: Connect to GROUND/GND

Please help me for rest 3 colors: RED, ORANGE and BROWN

Comment: You don't decide what the function of the wire is from the colour. Check out the pin-outs for connectors. But red is most commonly +5 VDC. Check this out: http://pinouts.ru/Slots/USB_pinout.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Their is no standard on the colour the cables inside a USB cable are the only way to know what each does is to trace it from the connector where the standards apply

Diagram for Type A & B

[image: Type A USB]

---

Tracing the cable from the connectors will be the only guaranteed way of knowing which cable is which